# Writing a file from StreamReader stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, stream

Im currently trying to downlaod a audio track from a WCF, i need some help writing it to the harddisk, how do i configure streamwriter or other to do this in a webApp?

```
// Use Service to download stream (returns System.IO.Stream) 
Stream stream = MyService.Download(("1231"));
// ReadStream
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
reader.ReadToEnd();

// Write this stream to a file/Hard disk
???
```

Comment: StreamReader is for text data

Comment: woops -_- only dealt with text in streams before this thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
Stream stream = MyService.Download(("1231"));
using (Stream s = File.Create(path))
{
    stream.CopyTo(s);
}
```

Comment: This is how it should be done, but it won't work with his code unless he uses something other than StreamReader or does something like `var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(28591));`

Comment: Do you know how to do the same in .Net 3.5?

Comment: @Fayilt with a loop. `void CopyTo(Stream from, Stream to)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[0x10000];
            int read = from.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            while (read > 0)
            {
                to.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                read = from.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

        }`

Comment: wth?? he is asking for StreamReader class not Stream.